# Объекты классов-оболочек в Java

Tags: java, классы, типы

Объект любого из классов-оболочек представляет собой полноценный экземпляр в динамической памяти, в котором хранится его неизменяемое значение.
Что подразумевается под неизменяемым значением?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Неизменяемое значение - это значение примитива, для которого объект является оболочкой. К примеру, для `int` - оболочка `java.lang.Integer` для `long` - оболочка - `java.lang.Long`.

Чтобы убедиться - открываем исходный код класса `java.lang.Integer` :

```
/**
 * The value of the {@code Integer}.
 *
 * @serial
 */
private final int value;

/**
 * Constructs a newly allocated {@code Integer} object that
 * represents the specified {@code int} value.
 *
 * @param   value   the value to be represented by the
 *                  {@code Integer} object.
 */
public Integer(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Вот это `private final int value` и есть неизменяемое значение.

**UPD:**
То есть объявляя `Integer somevar = 1;` на самом деле, выполняется нечто вроде: `Integer somevar = new Integer(1);` далее, если мы захотим поменять значение `somevar = 2` - то переменная `somevar` будет указывать уже на другой объект, а не перезатрет значение предыдущего. а предыдущий объект, будет собран сборщиком сусора, если на него более не имеется ссылок

Comment: Почему такой код работает? По идее мы не может изменять значение таким образом.    
Integer var = new Integer(0);
var = 1;

Comment: @jisecayeyo - обновил ответ.

Comment: @cache, в а чем заключается преимущество `final` в данном случае? Почему бы просто в данном объекте не менять значение переменной `value`?

Comment: @n199a если не использовать final то значение поля value можно будет изменить используя reflection или другой программист, который будет поддерживать код сможет нечаянно добавить для него сеттер. таким образом, класс потеряет такую характеристику как thread safety

Comment: @cache, смотри. Пусть пользователь добавляет сеттер и меняет значение переменной *без создания нового объекта*. По ресурсоемкости `изменение значения переменной` будет `менее трудозатратным` по сравнению с созданием экземпляра объекта. А про `thread safety` встает вопрос о `целесообразности` использования данной концепции в конкретно данной ситуации.